# json object with nested structures in golang

Tags: json, go

I have the following json object that I am trying to represent with Go as a `type JsonObject struct` 
and pass it back in its original json so that I can return the json as an api endpoint.  Any advice/example?

```
[{
    "time": 173000,
    "id": "VLSuEE5m1kmIhgE7ZhHDFe",
    "height": "",
    "DATASTRUCTURE": {

    },
    "language": "en",
    "size": 0,
    "url": "http://www.gstatic.com/play.m3u8",
    "type": "vid",
    "definitionid": "h264",
    "reference": "PAN-EN",
    "content": "This is some content",
    "revisiondate": "2017-11-29T00:00:00",
    "data": {

    },
    "id": "BBBB3424-153E-49DE-4786-013B6611BBBB",
    "thumbs": {
        "32": "https://www.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRj",
        "64": "https://www.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:DPd3GcRj"
    },
    "title": "Cafeteria",
    "hash": "BBBB5d39bea20edf76c94133be61BBBB"
}]
```

Comment: first of all your json is not valid, There are two `id` in the same object.
and according to the data you have `type JsonObject map[string]interface{}` might suit you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/  to generate struct for the given json schema.
For example, json given in the question can be represented like:

```
type AutoGenerated []struct {
Time          int    `json:"time"`
ID            string `json:"id"`
Height        string `json:"height"`
DATASTRUCTURE struct {
} `json:"DATASTRUCTURE"`
Language     string `json:"language"`
Size         int    `json:"size"`
URL          string `json:"url"`
Type         string `json:"type"`
Definitionid string `json:"definitionid"`
Reference    string `json:"reference"`
Content      string `json:"content"`
Revisiondate string `json:"revisiondate"`
Data         struct {
} `json:"data"`
Thumbs struct {
    Num32 string `json:"32"`
    Num64 string `json:"64"`
} `json:"thumbs"`
Title string `json:"title"`
Hash  string `json:"hash"`}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is exactly what I used.  What I am trying to do next is pass it in a func as such:  `profile := JsonObject{173000,"VLSuEE5m1kmIhgE7ZhHDFe","","en",0,"http://video/playlist.m3u8","m3u8","h264","PAN-EN","","2016-09-29T00:00:00"}

  body, _ := json.Marshal(profile)` . I am not sure how to handle the DATASTRUCTURE portion.

Comment: The `DATASTRUCTURE` part is an empty object. No need set anything in the Go code.

Comment: but I have to pass someting otherwise the JsonObject complains that I am not passing the same amount of fields.  I can't just pass "" for it.

Comment: @FutureDroid You can skip `DATASTRUCTURE` field in the Go code.